# using os without having to reset shell

Tags: python-3.x, operating-system

I have been trying to use `powershell` `promot` in windows from Python but when I type:

```
import os
os.system("powershell")
os.system("ls")
```

... it resets its `promot`s. As you know cmd does not accept the `ls` command. I am looking for away to make the terminal not reset itself after every command.

Comment: Do you want to run ls in powershell which I stunned from Python?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`powershell` is *interactive* command which blocks your Python code. Maybe a sort of `powershell -c 'ls'` would suffice?